# Call overwritten template method in derived class in C++ and MSVC 19

Tags: c++, templates, cross-platform

I am currently porting C++ code that works on Linux (GCC) to Windows (MSVC). I came across some code that I supposed should work.

Let's say we have some class that defines an `at` method that only accepts integral values:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct foo {
  auto at(std::integral auto const... is) const {}
};
```

(I will use `struct`s to make everything public by default.)

Now we derive `bar` from `foo` that overwrites the `at` method with another `at` method that only accepts floating point values:

```cpp
struct bar : foo {
  auto at(std::floating_point auto const... is) const {}
};
```

No I thought if I add `using foo::at;` in `bar`, `foo`s `at` method should become available in `bar`.

```cpp
struct bar : foo {
  using foo::at; // THIS LINE IS NEW
  auto at(std::floating_point auto const... is) const {}
};
```

If I now call the `at` method with some ints on an instance of `bar` GCC, Clang and MSVC do not seem to agree on if that's possible or not. Only GCC compiles this code. Clang and MSVC basically say that they cannot find an `at` that takes ints.

```cpp
auto main() -> int {
  auto const f = bar{};
  f.at(2,3); // Only works with GCC
}
```

[(See here on compiler explorer)](https://godbolt.org/z/o1P4dGhz9)

**QUESTIONS**

1. Which compiler is wrong or right?
2. Is there a solution for all compilers?

If I got it right from the [standard specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) GCC seems to be wrong and Clang and MSVC correctly do not compile the code. Am I right?

Comment: you can only override virtual methods. You cannot override a non virtual method

Comment: Overwrite! not override. You can indeed overwrite a method. I agree on overriding virtual methods.